# Condense all my snippets into one file in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, code-snippets

I have a multitude of snippets for each tag in the language I am currently programming in. I want to share these with some of my co-workers but I don't want to send them like 30 snippet files. Is there a way to condense these into one file (apart from zipping them, sending the zip and then having them unzip it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`.sublime-completions`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html) file. These are JSON-formatted files that contain the target scope at the top, then a series of completions with a trigger and contents. For example, the following snippet

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[function ${1:function_name} (${2:argument}) {
    ${0:// body...}
}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>fun</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
    <description>Function</description>
</snippet>
```

can be turned into this completion:

```js
{
    "scope": "source.js",

    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "fun", "contents": "function ${1:function_name} (${2:argument}) {\n    ${0:// body...}\n}" }
    ]
}
```

Use `\n` for newlines and `\t` for tab characters in the `"contents"` section. Double quotes need to be escaped as well. Also, you can use `\t` to separate the trigger from a brief description on what the completion is about, it will be displayed right-aligned and slightly grayed and does not affect the trigger itself:

```js
{ "trigger": "fun\tFunction", "contents": "function ${1:function_name} (${2:argument}) {\n    ${0:// body...}\n}" }
```

Since this is [JSON](http://json.org), to add multiple completions just put a comma `,` after the closing curly brace `}` of the completion, and put your next one on the next line. The final line should not have a final comma.

Good luck!